# "Спать без задних ног"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение этого выражения. Почему без задних ног?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение ироническое. Насколько понимаю, в полной форме должно звучать примерно как "Набегался как собака, спит без задних ног". 
Вроде бы от усталости у собак перестают слушаться в первую очередь задние ноги. И они же в первую очередь "отдыхают" при первой возможности.

По другой версии - речь может идти о лошадях, но с аналогичным обоснованием. Видимо, это довольно распространённое свойство среди братьев наших меньших.